# Loop de Linha e Coluna em PHP

Tags: php

Eu estou tentando fazer um loop onde a cada 5 registros na linha, pula uma linha e assim continua até chega a 6 linhas, quando chegar a 6 linhas para o laço.

Exemplo:

```
12345
12345
12345
12345
12345
12345
Para o laço
```

Obrigado

Comment: E qual é o código que está tentando? Deu algum erro ou apenas o resultado foi inesperado? Se deu erro, qual foi? Se o resultado saiu estranho, o que deu de diferente? Complete sua pergunta com essas informações que poderemos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Fiz um correção na resposta, veja se funciona pra você usando conceito de módulo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer usando uma condição com `%`modulo. Seria algo como.

```
if($item%5==0){
   // insira o item + <br/> <-- onde br representa a quebra de linha
else 
   // insira o item normalmente
```

A lógica é o seguinte: o operador porcento `%` significa módulo na programação, que verifica o resto da divisão de um determinado valor. Neste seu caso é assim, toda vez que o valor do `$item` for dividido por `5` e seu resto for `0`, então faça algo. Como no exemplo, é colocado a tag `<BR/>` para pular uma linha. Veja mais detalhes [na documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/internals2.opcodes.mod.php).

Agora veja um código completo aqui usando PDO. Veja:

```
<?php   

    // Instancia o objeto PDO
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '');
    // define para que o PDO lance exceções caso ocorra erros
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT id FROM category;");

    $item = 1;
    while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // aqui eu mostro os valores de minha consulta

        if($item%5==0)
            echo "{$linha['id']}<br/>";
        else 
            echo "{$linha['id']}";
        }        
        $item++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Olá Ack Lay. Tudo bem ? Desculpe minha falta de conhecimento, mas eu não entendi o significado da (%)  no IF, senão for incomodar, você poderia explicar melhor a lógica. Eu quero aprender. E obrigado pela ajuda amigo.

Comment: Obrigado Ack Lay.

Comment: Eu tenho outra duvida com a query

Comment: Se sua dúvida já não possuir nenhum tópico relacionado aqui na comunidade, sinta-se a vontade em abrir uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Pergunta aberta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183976/query-para-campo-de-busca Obrigado