# Query para Campo de Busca

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Preciso fazer uma *query* que busque todos os registros que possua o termo digitado em um *input*, por exemplo: Carro, seja retornado carro azul, carro verde, etc...

Minha *query* atual:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM veiculos WHERE nome = '$veiculo'";
```

Obrigado

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM veiculos WHERE nome LIKE '%$veiculo%'";`

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes usar o operador [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like). Sua *query* ficaria desta forma:

```
"SELECT * FROM veiculos WHERE nome LIKE '%$veiculo'%";
```

Veja mais detalhes [na documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html).

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.